# No text in dynamically created CheckBox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

As you saw in the title I'm creating dynamic checkboxes with this code:

```
private void create_checks(int nr, string name)
{
    checkBox[nr] = new CheckBox();
    checkBox[nr].Size = new Size(20, 43);
    checkBox[nr].Name = name;
    checkBox[nr].Text = name;
    checkBox[nr].Location = new Point(40, 20 + (nr * 20));
    this.Controls.Add(checkBox[nr]);
}
```

But the checkboxes have no text, can someone help me?

Comment: What happens if you increase the width of the checkbox to, say, 200? Is the label just cut off?

Comment: I increased the width, but still nothing and no the label is not  cut off, simply appears with no text: http://postimg.org/image/wjl06y86p/

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint on that line and inspect the `Text` property? What's the value of `nr` and `name`?

Comment: That's strange, the checkBox[nr].Name gets it's name but the checkBox[nr].Text has nothing.

Comment: nr has value 0 and name "TEST"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the with:

```
checkBox[nr] = new CheckBox();
checkBox[nr].Size = new Size(120, 43);
checkBox[nr].Name = name;
checkBox[nr].Text = name;
checkBox[nr].Location = new Point(40, 20 + (nr * 20));
frm.Controls.Add(checkBox[nr]);
```

Comment: This is the error i get when i try it: 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Oh sorry I thought it was WPF. You just need to increase the size(with) in your example `checkBox[nr] = new CheckBox();
            checkBox[nr].Size = new Size(120, 43);
            checkBox[nr].Name = name;
            checkBox[nr].Text = name;
            checkBox[nr].Location = new Point(40, 20 + (nr * 20));
            this.Controls.Add(checkBox[nr]);`

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work last time but now works, Thanks for the help!